# Search number in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Im trying to search a number in a datagridview. 
When I try to Search for texts, it work perfect. But, when I try to search for numbers, it's not working. In my column I have numbers like: 1,2,22,33. So, When i type:2 in the textbox I'd like to see the numbers 2 and 22 in the datagridview.

Here is my code:

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataView dv = new DataView(tablecourse);
        string value = "CCarga LIKE %{0}%"; //Here is the error

        dv.RowFilter = string.Format(value, txtSearch.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv; 
    }
```

**Error**: Missing operator before MOD operator.

**When I try**:string value = "CCarga LIKE '%{0}%'";

**I get:** Not possible to do the operation 'Like' em System.UInt32 e System.String.

**UPDATE**: Here is the change.

```
value = "CONVERT(CCarga, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'";
```

Comment: What is the type of the `CCarga` column?

Comment: int, I believe I have to do something like: Convert to int 32, but i'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Is the field contains 234 and you search for 34, you want to have that row included?

Comment: So you just want to have the rows of which the value of the `CCarga` int column equals the integer value in `txtSearch.Text`?

Comment: No. If I have stored the numbers 22 e 222, when the user types 2, it will show both of the numbers. Also, tried what you said and got missing operator after = '

Comment: The question is not longer clear. Can you provide sample data input and expected output?

Comment: Based on your update, Anil Kumar's answer (the second part) should work for you. Did you try `CONVERT( CCarga , System.String) LIKE '%2%'`?

Comment: Ya, just like that. I'll suggest Anil Kumar to edit and upload his answer, if you don't mind

Comment: Sure. I think that his answer is just missing a "%". Probably a typo.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: oh, thanks. Wasn't aware of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 string value = "CCarga LIKE '%{0}%'"; //Here is the error
```

add single quote to after and before %

**Update after int type added to the question**

Then convert it to string, something like below, you need to give  a .NET type,

```
  value = "CONVERT(CCarga, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'";  ;
```

You should refer [usage of data view filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx), it by .net fx not by sql server.

Comment: Can't. It's an INT collum. I edited the post, check it there.